# Asp.net - Jquery Takes Two Clicks to Hide Div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a registration page for two types of users (temp/permanent) and i need to display only parts of the form to each user. I am trying to achieve this by hiding certain div elements using jquery. the problem is my DIV element hides momentarily and re-appears within a second. i tried looking at multiple solutions but none seem to work. this is my code.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#<%=releasetype.ClientID%>").click(function () {
              var reltype = $("input[name='<%=releasetype.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();
                if (reltype == "Temporary") {
                    document.getElementById('pm').style.display = 'none';
                } else if (reltype == "Permanent") {
                    document.getElementById('pm').style.display = 'block';
                } 
            });

        });
</script>
```

.aspx

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="releasetype" cssclass="radio" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
                <asp:ListItem>Temporary</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Permanent</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

          <div id="pm" class="form-horizontal">
<asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="PrimaryID" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>             
          </div>
```

i tried using event.preventDefault(); & return false; in my code. But both methods did not stop the page from refreshing.

Comment: Please show the actual HTML code, not server-side code that we can not easily reproduce. [mcve]

Comment: Hi you are using ASP .NET web forms set the AutoPostBack property false of the radio button list

Comment: tried it vignesh, did not fix it. - Actually tried setting it to false. still the same

Comment: UPDATE: It needs two clicks for the hide to work, the first click hides the div element for one sec, and after second click the element hides

Comment: If you're only doing front-end work, then you don't have to use `Server Controls`. Why do you need to `Postback` on the radio button? Do you really need to/does it do any work? If not, just use plain HTML `input`

Answer (score 0):

I was calling two events and that was what caused the misbehavior

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#<%=releasetype.ClientID%>").click(function () {
```

calling only one, either on page load or on button click solved the issue.